# Subview's bounds are zero in layoutSubviews()

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

The bounds of a subview of a subview of a custom `UIView` seem to be 0 in `layoutSubviews()`, hence using the bounds in `layoutSubviews()` is a problem.

To show the problem I put a demo on GitHub: [SOBoundsAreZero](https://github.com/drjackyl-s-repos-for-questions/SOBoundsAreZero)

Here's a direct link to the custom view's implementation: [DemoView.swift](https://github.com/drjackyl-s-repos-for-questions/SOBoundsAreZero/blob/master/BoundsAreZero/DemoView.swift)

The structure of the custom view "DemoView" is like this:

```
DemoView
    firstLevelSubview
        secondLevelSubview
```

This structure is being created programmatically using Auto Layout.

When `layoutSubviews()` is called, the view and the firstLevelSubview have the expected bounds, but the secondLevelSubview's bounds are 0.

I expected all subviews using Auto Layout to have the correct bounds, at least in the last call to `layoutSubviews`.

The structure is an abstraction of a real case. To avoid the problem, secondLevelSubview could be added as a first level subview to DemoView. Though, this is something, that is not feasible in the real case.

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, even if it's expected behaviour.

Comment: Did you add constraint and set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false ?

Comment: @Vicaren, yes, it's set. I added a link to the implementation for convenience.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I was able to fix this with a call to `secondLevelSubview.layoutIfNeeded()` in `layoutSubviews()`.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    secondLevelSubview.layoutIfNeeded()

    firstLevelSubview.layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2
    secondLevelSubview.layer.cornerRadius = secondLevelSubview.bounds.width / 2

    print("bounds.width: \(bounds.width), contentView.bounds.width: \(firstLevelSubview.bounds.width), backgroundView.bounds.width: \(secondLevelSubview.bounds.width)")
}
```

---

The description of `layoutIfNeeded()` is:

> Use this method to force the view to update its layout immediately.
>   When using Auto Layout, the layout engine updates the position of
>   views as needed to satisfy changes in constraints. Using the view that
>   receives the message as the root view, this method lays out the view
>   subtree starting at the root. If no layout updates are pending, this
>   method exits without modifying the layout or calling any
>   layout-related callbacks.

So, essentially you have an ordering issue here.  The subview is scheduled for layout, and *Auto Layout* will get to it, but it hasn't done it yet.  By calling `layoutIfNeeded()`, you tell *Auto Layout* to perform the pending layout immediately so that you can get the updated frame information.

**Note:** You can also just call `self.layoutIfNeeded()` and that will layout `DemoView` and all of its subviews.  This would be useful if you had many such subviews and didn't want to have to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on each of them.

Comment: Thanks @vacawama, this makes most sense to me. Calling `layoutIfNeeded()` in the function, that sets up the constraints, after doing so, makes sense to me. I think that was the "simple thing", that I missed.

Comment: The interesting thing is, if you call `layoutIfNeeded()` in `setupViews()` `layoutSubviews()` will be called twice, first with a frame of `0`, and then with the correct frame.  If you put the call to `layoutIfNeeded()` in `layoutSubviews()`, the corner radius values will be set only once to the correct values.  Both end up in the same place.

Comment: In the real case I also saw, that calling `layoutIfNeeded()` in `setupViews()` won't have the desired effect. So it seems, it should be called on the subview itself in `layoutSubviews()`, as your answer primarily states. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

First, Your view is being construed without problem cause you have an initializer based on ‘CGRect’ , so it gets its dimension!
Second, 
Your first subview get initialized after its parents view has got its dimensions. First subview dimensions depends on the parent view dimensions which are ready. So no problem here as you mentioned. 
But meanwhile your first subview is trying to get its dimensions, your second subview also starts to get its dimensions based on first subview which is not ready yet , so it got nothing. 
I suggest make different functions for each subview. 
Make your object from the view class with its frame initializer  in Your view controller. In ‘viewDidLoad’ call first subview function and in ’viewDidLoadSubView’ call second subview function. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired result, if you try to access `UIView.bounds` under main queue.

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.firstLevelSubview.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width / 2
        self.secondLevelSubview.layer.cornerRadius = self.secondLevelSubview.bounds.width / 2
        print("bounds.width: \(self.bounds.width), contentView.bounds.width: \(self.firstLevelSubview.bounds.width), backgroundView.bounds.width: \(self.secondLevelSubview.bounds.width)")
    }
}

//print:
//bounds.width: 64.0, contentView.bounds.width: 64.0, backgroundView.bounds.width: 54.0
```

But why? So here I dig down into your problem. Here is the calling view hierarchy of your `DemoView` layoutSubviews method

```
DemoView
|
|___layoutSubviews
    |
    |___firstLevelSubview
        |
        |___layoutSubviews //Here you are trying to access bounds of second view which is still need to be resize or achieve it's bound
            |
            |___ secondLevelSubview
                | 
                |___layoutSubviews
```

And so in this case, main queue will help you to get the actual bounds of any `UIView.subView`.

Another case I did it, I try to add `secondLevelSubview` to the `DemoView` itself with the `firstLevelSubview` constraints like below:

```
fileprivate func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

    firstLevelSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    firstLevelSubview.layer.masksToBounds = true
    firstLevelSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    addSubview(firstLevelSubview)
    firstLevelSubview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive = true
    firstLevelSubview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive = true
    firstLevelSubview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    firstLevelSubview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive = true

    secondLevelSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    secondLevelSubview.layer.masksToBounds = true
    secondLevelSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.magenta
//  firstLevelSubview.addSubview(secondLevelSubview)
    addSubview(secondLevelSubview) //Here
    secondLevelSubview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLevelSubview.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.84).isActive = true
    secondLevelSubview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLevelSubview.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.84).isActive = true
    secondLevelSubview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLevelSubview.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    secondLevelSubview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstLevelSubview.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

And the hierarchy it follows like below:

```
DemoView
    |
    |___layoutSubviews
        |
        |___firstLevelSubview
            |
            |___layoutSubviews
            |
            |___secondLevelSubview
            |
            |___layoutSubviews
```

So, in the above case if you try to print the `UIView.bounds` without any main queue you will get the desired result.

Let me know, this helps you to understand the hierarchy.